# Saltwater fish identification

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

Can someone please identify this fish. Someone had asked me to rehome this fish but they were unsure what type of fish it is. Right now I have it in a quarantine tank until I find out what type of fish it is. I know it is some sort of clown but I cannot find the specific type after that. The fish is the one in the foreground of the image being black and white. It is a saltwater fish.

[image: Black and White Fish]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know it is some sort of clown but I cannot find the specific type after that.

This is a juvenile *[Plectorhinchus chaetodonoides](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harlequin_sweetlips?wprov=sfla1)*, which carries the nickname of "Harliquin sweetlips". With respect to the [clownfish](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphiprioninae?wprov=sfla1), they are similar up to the order [Perciformes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perciformes?wprov=sfla1).

[image]

[image]

> Juveniles are brown with large white blotches and mimic the movement of a poisonous flatworm for defence against predators. They gain more spots and the spots reverse from white to black as they age.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can do research on type compatibility. I appreciate it